# async/await за кулисами

Tags: c#, .net

Рихтер приводит вот такой код:

```
private static async Task<String> MyMethodAsync(Int32 argument) {
    Int32 local = argument;
    try {
        Type1 result1 = await Method1Async();
        for (Int32 x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
            Type2 result2 = await Method2Async();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception) {
        Console.WriteLine("Catch");
    }
    finally {
        Console.WriteLine("Finally");
    }
    return "Done";
}
```

И пишет, что за "кулисами" он разворачивается вот в такое месиво:

```
  [DebuggerStepThrough, AsyncStateMachine(typeof(StateMachine))]
    private static Task<String> MyMethodAsync(Int32 argument)
    {
        // Создание экземпляра конечного автомата и его инициализация
        StateMachine stateMachine = new StateMachine()
        {
            // Создание построителя, возвращающего Task<String>.
            // Конечный автомат обращается к построителю для назначения
            // завершения задания или выдачи исключения.
            m_builder = AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<String>.Create(),
            m_state = 1,
            // инициализация местонахождения
            m_argument = argument // Копирование аргументов в поля конечного
        }; // автомата
           // Начало выполнения конечного автомата.
        stateMachine.m_builder.Start(ref stateMachine);
        return stateMachine.m_builder.Task; // Возвращение задания конечного
    } // автомата
      // Структура конечного автомата
    [CompilerGenerated, StructLayout(LayoutKind.Auto)]
    private struct StateMachine : IAsyncStateMachine
    {
        // Поля для построителя конечного автомата (Task) и его местонахождения
        public AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<String> m_builder;
        public Int32 m_state;
        // Аргумент и локальные переменные становятся полями:
        public Int32 m_argument, m_local, m_x;
        public Type1 m_resultType1;
        public Type2 m_resultType2;
        // Одно поле на каждый тип Awaiter.
        // В любой момент времени важно только одно из этих полей. В нем
        // хранится ссылка на последний выполненный экземпляр await,
        // который завершается асинхронно:
        private TaskAwaiter<Type1> m_awaiterType1;
        private TaskAwaiter<Type2> m_awaiterType2;
        // Сам конечный автомат
        void IAsyncStateMachine.MoveNext()
        {
            String result = null; // Результат Task
                                  // Вставленный компилятором блок try гарантирует
                                  // завершение задания конечного автомата
            try
            {
                Boolean executeFinally = true; // Логический выход из блока 'try'
                if (m_state == 1)
                { // Если метод конечного автомата
                  // выполняется впервые
                    m_local = m_argument; // Выполнить начало исходного метода
                }
                // Блок try из исходного кода
                try
                {
                    TaskAwaiter<Type1> awaiterType1;
                    TaskAwaiter<Type2> awaiterType2;
                    switch (m_state)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            // Начало исполнения кода в 'try'
                            // вызвать Method1Async и получить его объект ожидания
                            awaiterType1 = Method1Async().GetAwaiter();
                            if (!awaiterType1.IsCompleted)
                            {
                                m_state = 0; // 'Method1Async'
                                             // завершается асинхронно
                                m_awaiterType1 = awaiterType1; // Сохранить объект
                                                               // ожидания до возвращения
                                                               // Приказать объекту ожидания вызвать MoveNext
                                                               // после завершения операции
                                m_builder.AwaitUnsafeOnCompleted(ref awaiterType1, ref this);
                                // Предыдущая строка вызывает метод OnCompleted
                                // объекта awaiterType1, что приводит к вызову
                                // ContinueWith(t => MoveNext()) для Task.
                                // При завершении Task ContinueWith вызывает MoveNext
                                executeFinally = false; // Без логического выхода
                                                        // из блока 'try'
                                return; // Поток возвращает
                            } // управление вызывающей стороне
                              // 'Method1Async' завершается синхронно.
                            break;
                        case 0: // 'Method1Async' завершается асинхронно
                            awaiterType1 = m_awaiterType1; // Восстановление последнего
                            break; // объекта ожидания
                        case 1: // 'Method2Async' завершается асинхронно
                            awaiterType2 = m_awaiterType2; // Восстановление последнего
                            goto ForLoopEpilog; // объекта ожидания
                    }
                    // После первого await сохраняем результат и запускаем цикл 'for'

                    m_resultType1 = awaiterType1.GetResult(); // Получение результата
                    ForLoopPrologue:
                    m_x = 0; // Инициализация цикла 'for'
                    goto ForLoopBody; // Переход к телу цикла 'for'
                    ForLoopEpilog:
                    m_resultType2 = awaiterType2.GetResult();
                    m_x++; // Увеличение x после каждой итерации
                           // Переход к телу цикла 'for'
                    ForLoopBody:
                    if (m_x < 3)
                    { // Условие цикла 'for'
                      // Вызов Method2Async и получение объекта ожидания
                        awaiterType2 = Method2Async().GetAwaiter();
                        if (!awaiterType2.IsCompleted)
                        {
                            m_state = 1; // 'Method2Async' завершается
                                         // асинхронно
                            m_awaiterType2 = awaiterType2; // Сохранение объекта
                                                           // ожидания до возвращения
                                                           // Приказываем вызвать MoveNext при завершении операции
                            m_builder.AwaitUnsafeOnCompleted(ref awaiterType2, ref this);
                            executeFinally = false; // Без логического выхода
                                                    // из блока 'try'
                            return; // Поток возвращает управление
                        } // вызывающей стороне
                          // 'Method2Async' завершается синхронно
                        goto ForLoopEpilog; // Синхронное завершение, возврат
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Catch");
                }
                finally
                {
                    // Каждый раз, когда блок физически выходит из 'try',
                    // выполняется 'finally'.
                    // Этот код должен выполняться только при логическом
                    // выходе из 'try'.
                    if (executeFinally)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Finally");
                    }
                }
                result = "Done"; // То, что в конечном итоге должна вернуть
            } // асинхронная функция.
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                // Необработанное исключение: задание конечного автомата
                // завершается с исключением.
                m_builder.SetException(exception);
                return;
            }
            // Исключения нет: задание конечного автомата завершается с результатом
            m_builder.SetResult(result);
        }
```

Я правильно понимаю, что вся "магия" восстановления потока выполнения с точки прерывания сводится к повторным вызовам исходного с самого метода, но в зависимости от состояний какие-то куски кода просто пропускаются так как считаются выполненными?

Comment: "месево" - от слова "mess" или от слова "месить"?

Comment: Вы понимаете правильно, но лучше ознакомьтесь с конечными автоматами: это одна из тех тем, которые полезно знать хорошему программисту.